# Finite Icon Colors in Draftail Editor

Tags: wagtail

I am trying to implement a finite number of colors (like square icons) on the [Draftail](https://github.com/springload/draftail) editor itself. What will be the best way to approach this?

It should be similar to how Microsoft Word displays the font color or something along those lines.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if it's the best approach but here is what I came up with:

https://gist.github.com/benoitvogel/46022124d46de03ed2078603fb24ca97

This defines a new inline style which encloses the selected text between `<span class="mycustomclass"></span>` (change `feature_name` according to the CSS class you want to use).

Then, you just have to define the corresponding `.mycustomstyle` CSS class in your frontend as usual:

```
.mycustomstyle {
    color: purple;
}
```

You can also modify `control['style']` to change the way this style will be displayed in the editor.

You will get 1 icon/label per CSS class, so it's not really like in Word as you won't get a proper selector. I haven't tried it myself, but according to [Wagtail docs](http://docs.wagtail.io/en/latest/advanced_topics/customisation/extending_draftail.html) `icon` can reference SVG, so you might be able to display color squares instead of labels.

Hope it fits your needs.

Comment: This is great. It gives me a starting point to implement colors as icons and see how it goes. Thanks!

Comment: I'm surprised `f'{tag} class="{feature_name}"'` works, definitely don't rely on this :) – also you can reference SVG but it's with `icon`, not `label`.

Comment: @ThibaudColas Thanks for your comment. Could you please elaborate a little bit more and give us better directions? The documentation is great but still sparse on this subject ATM. In fact, an example would be much appreciated.

Comment: Your whole answer is accurate except for the `label` that's meant to be `icon`. Have you seen https://github.com/springload/draftail#icons? Those docs are meant to be more complete, and the demo site contains examples.

Comment: @ThibaudColas Thanks, I updated my answer accordingly. About the Draftail Readme, I have read it but I still have to figure out how the Python register_custom_style_feature() function is turned into JS.